# Выдача доступа к отправке формы

Tags: spring, безопасность, spring-security, request, webapp2

Вот SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/registration","/questions/add"
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/questions")
public class QuestionController {
    private final QuestionService questionService;

    public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService) {
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String listQuestions(Model model) {
        List<Question> questions = questionService.getAllQuestions();
        model.addAttribute("questions", questions);
        return "questions/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addQuestionForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("question", new Question());
        return "questions/add";
    }


    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addQuestionSubmit(@ModelAttribute Question question) {
        questionService.addQuestion(question.getTopic(), question.getQuestion());
        return "redirect:/questions";
    }
}
```

И сама форма

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Добавить вопрос</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Добавить вопрос</h1>
<form action="/questions/add" method="post">
  <label for="topic">Тема:</label>
  <input type="text" id="topic" name="topic" required><br>

  <label for="question">Вопрос:</label>
  <textarea id="question" name="question" required></textarea><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Проблема в том, что при обычной загрузке все хорошо, но когда я отправляю форму выдает отказ в доступе 403. Только начинаю, поэтому если можно с объяснением